# pass query string get value into url link

Tags: php, query-string

I am trying to pass in a $_GET variable from a query string and pass it into a link to another page that has an application on it.

A customer will be directed to my page and the url will have the variable name merchantid.  I need to take that on the home page, and pass it to the application page.

I've got it displaying on the home page as a test, so I know how to get it.  I just need to know how to pass it the application page.

```
<?php
    if (empty($_GET)) {
        // no data passed by get
        echo "<a href='{site_url}application'>Application</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        // The value of the variable name is found
        echo "<a href='{site_url}application?merchantid=" .merchantid ."'><Application></a>";
    }
?>
```

My else link actually blows up currently.

Ok, here is my second try, with the same result.  The link blows up when I pass in the merchantid into the url.  Ex.  www.mysite.com/?=merchantid=12345

```
<?php
    if (empty($_GET)) {
        // no data passed by get
        echo "<a href='{site_url}application'>Application</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        if(isset($_GET['merchantid'])){$merchantid = $_GET['merchantid'];}
        else{$merchantid = "DefaultMerchant";}
            echo "<a href='{$site_url}application?merchantid=" .$merchantid ."'><Application </a>";                                     
    }
?>
```

Comment: where does merchantid (is $ missing?!) come from?

Comment: The problem is not clear - do you call the PHP with merchantid as a query parameter and ask how to access it? Does the PHP produce error messages??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why your code is not working

You're not telling php that "merchantid" is a variable nor you're defining it.

### Solution

Replace

```
echo "<a href='{site_url}application?merchantid=" .merchantid ."'><Application></a>";
```

With

```
if(isset($_GET['merchantid'])){$merchantid = $_GET['merchantid'];}
else{$merchantid = "";}
echo "<a href='{$site_url}application?merchantid=" .$merchantid ."'><Application></a>";
}
```

---

### Updated code

```
<?php
$site_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
    if (empty($_GET)) {
        // no data passed by get
        echo "<a href='{$site_url}application'>Application</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        if(isset($_GET['merchantid'])){$merchantid = $_GET['merchantid'];}
        else{$merchantid = "DefaultMerchant";}
            echo "<a href='{$site_url}application?merchantid=".$merchantid."'>Application</a>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: where is `$merchantid` defined?

Comment: unless you've previously assigned $_GET['merchatid'] to the variable $merchantid, you should use $_GET['merchantid'] instead. Also, dont forget the isset() check to avoid php notices.

Comment: There is still a problem with this code; if `$_GET['merchantid']` is not defined then `$merchantid` will not get defined and so will produce warnings when you try to read from it. +1 for edit

Comment: @andrew in the previous version of the answer the link wasn't echoed if $_GET['merchantid'] wasn't set, anyway I updated again my answer, this will output in any case the link :) Thanks for your feedback

Comment: See my revised code.  I'm confused about how to display the link in my inner If statement.  It looks like I'm not setting anything for the If statement.

Answer (score 1):

$_GET is an array indexed by whatever values are in the query string. For example:

```
http://sit.url.com?merchantId=12&foo=bar
```

would place the following in the $_GET array:

```
$_GET['merchantId'] = "12"
$_GET['foo'] = "bar"
```

You will want a block in your code to initialize a $merchantId variable based on the presence of those values from $_GET:

```
//folks commonly use ternaries for this:
$merchantId = (isset($_GET['merchantId'])) ? $_GET['merchantId'] : false
```

Which is a shorthand way of stating:

```
if (isset($_GET['merhantId']) {
  $merchantId = $_GET['merchantId']
} else {
  $merchantId = false;
}
```

As Angelo and C.Coggins mentioned, don't forget the "$" in front of your variable in php.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to assign `$_GET['merchantid']` to `$merchantid` first, or replace `$merchantid` with `$_GET['merchantid']` **unless** you have register_globals turned on, which you really shouldn't use.

So either add this:

```
$merchantid = $_GET['merchantid'];
```

or use this:

```
echo "<a href='{$site_url}application?merchantid=" . $_GET['merchantid'] . "'><Application></a>";
```

Besides that, as others pointed out, your original code is missing a `$` before the variable name.

Comment: you should check `isset($_GET['merchantid'])` otherwise either of your solutions could produce warnings

Comment: True. I was only meaning to point out how to get the `$_GET['merchantid']` value as the OP requested.